# "find" finding a character that "findr" cant

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to determine whether a given C function requires any input arguments and then if the type is void i do some further processing.
To do that, i read the funciton's signature into a string and then search for the last "(","void",")" inside that string. if the returned values by rfind are in that exact order, then i have a hit.
Here's the code:

```
std::string::size_type positionvoidkeyword = FuncSigStringVoid.rfind("void");
std::string::size_type positionclosebracket = FuncSigStringVoid.rfind(')');
std::string::size_type positionopenbracket = FuncSigStringVoid.find('(');

if (positionvoidkeyword > positionopenbracket && positionvoidkeyword < positionclosebracket)
```

For all my other functions this works fine but for these two functions signatures, `rfind` wont find `(` inside the string but `find` manages to find it.

```
void myfunction( void   /*me is a mean comment and all ur base are belong to us!*/            )
double loco( void  )
```

My question is what could be causing this?

Comment: `rfind` works for me.

Comment: How are you handling `void bar(void*)`, `void foo(void(*)(void))`, and `void baz(int /*void*/)`?

Comment: `std::string FuncSigStringVoid = Rewrite.getRewrittenText(FuncDec->getSourceRange());` using llvm libraries like this. `FuncDec` is a `FunctionDecl` node. I'm using AStMatchers. I'm handling the string part in `MatchCallback` in `run`.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/mIebl4). I suspect that you're searching in different strings than you believe you are.

Comment: Why are you searching anyways (Don't you have the information when you decide to use a C-function)?

Comment: Its sorta like a round-about way to get the position of the void argument in a C funciton for automatic refactoring.

Comment: i found the problem. the problem was not with `find` or `rfind`. i was giving the `Rewriter` the `SourceRange` of the whole `FunctionDecl` which would sometimes include the definition of the function and would sometimes cause the mentioned problem.

Comment: so molbdnilo  was right. thank you.